# How to handle Empty array in codable decode process

Tags: json, swift, codable

It works well when "address" array is not empty. But it fails when "address" array is empty. Any help will be highly appreciated. I have struct for Address object. Basically "address" is array of object of type "Address" but when address is empty it fails.

```
{
    "success": "1",
    "message": "You have succesfully verified your mobile no",
    "details": {
        "customer_id": 825,
        "is_delivery_available": "0",
        "is_registration_complete": "0",
        "is_customer_verified": "0",
        "customer_status": "0",
        "cart_count": "0",
        "name_type": "mr",
        "firstname": "",
        "lastname": "",
        "full_name": "",
        "pincode": "",
        "profile_pic": "",
        "mobile": "8583846677",
        "email": "",
        "address": [

        ],
        "referral_code": ""
    }
}
```

Above is the JSON I am trying to decode using Codable in Swift4.

```
import Foundation

struct Signup: Codable {
    var success:String?
    var message:String?
    var details:Details?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case success, message, details }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        success = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .success)
        message = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .message)
        if let _details = try? values.decode(Details.self, forKey: .details) {
            details = _details
        }
    }
}

struct Details: Codable {
    var address:[Address]?
    var cart_count:String?
    var customer_id:String?
    var customer_status:String?
    var email:String?
    var firstname:String?
    var full_name:String?
    var is_customer_verified:String?
    var is_delivery_available:String?
    var is_registration_complete:String?
    var lastname:String?
    var mobile:String?
    var name_type:String?
    var pincode:String?
    var profile_pic:String?
    var referral_code:String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case address, cart_count, customer_id, customer_status, email, firstname, full_name, is_customer_verified, is_delivery_available, is_registration_complete, lastname, mobile, name_type, pincode, profile_pic, referral_code }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        ****-->>> Issue is in this line. How to handle empty array while decoding. <<<--****
        address = try? values.decode([Address].self, forKey: .address) 

        cart_count = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .cart_count)
        customer_id = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .customer_id)
        customer_status = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .customer_status)
        email = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .email)
        firstname = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .firstname)
        full_name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .full_name)
        is_customer_verified = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .is_customer_verified)
        is_delivery_available = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .is_delivery_available)
        is_registration_complete = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .is_registration_complete)
        lastname = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .lastname)
        mobile = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .mobile)
        name_type = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name_type)
        pincode = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .pincode)
        profile_pic = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .profile_pic)
        referral_code = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .referral_code)
    }
}

struct Address: Codable {
    var address_default:String?
    var address_id:String?
    var address_type:String?
    var city:String?
    var customer_id:String?
    var flat_or_house_or_office_no:String?
    var full_address:String?
    var full_name:String?
    var landmark:String?
    var lat:String?
    var lng:String?
    var mobile:String?
    var name_type:String?
    var pincode:String?
    var street_or_society_or_office_name:String?
}
```

I am stuck into this. How to handle empty array while decoding the json data in Swift4 Codable.

Comment: decodeIfPresent(_:forKey:) method for decoding

Comment: CommonResponse:Signup(success: Optional("1"), message: Optional("You have succesfully verified your mobile no"), details: nil) - not worked.

Answer (score 5):

I came across this problem and I did as below to solve this one.

```
if let _address = try? values.decode([Address].self, forKey: .address) {
    address = _address
} else {
    address = []
}
```

You can give it a try.

---

2022.06.08 updated.

according to @Amin Benarieb

```
let _address = try? values.decode([Address].self, forKey: .address) ?? []
```

Comment: Slight improve: 

let _address = try? values.decode([Address].self, forKey: .address)  ?? []

Comment: @andrew54069 Good one but what if I have something wrong in the parsing itself and not just an empty array? I won't be able to catch it for debugging purposes. Any suggestions?

Comment: then you can try catch yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The real issue is that `customer_id` in `Details` is `Int` not `String`. Decoding an empty array is supposed to work.

Your code is too complicated. Enjoy the magic of `Codable` and omit all CodingKeys and initializers and declare all struct members as non-optional and as constants

```
struct Signup: Decodable {
    let success : String
    let message : String
    let details : Details
}

struct Details : Decodable {
    let address : [Address]
    let cart_count : String
    let customer_id : Int
    let customer_status, email, firstname, full_name : String
    let is_customer_verified, is_delivery_available, is_registration_complete : String
    let lastname, mobile, name_type, pincode, profile_pic, referral_code : String
}

struct Address: Decodable {
    let address_default, address_id, address_type, city, customer_id : String
    let flat_or_house_or_office_no, full_address, full_name : String
    let landmark, lat, lng, mobile, name_type, pincode, street_or_society_or_office_name : String
}
```

You can even name the members *camelCased*

```
let cartCount : String
let customerId : Int
...
let isRegistrationComplete : String
```

and pass the `convertFromSnakeCase` key decoding strategy

```
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
```

Still no extra code!

Comment: can you really get rid of optionals if you're not sure the data will be there?  My  code is unable to parse an empty array as in "foo":[].  How should I code? Quick type suggested a lot of crazy classes and methods. The contents of the array if not empty are always strings, however, [String] throws error typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: @user6631314 The error message is related to the root object, not to a specific key.